# Creating HTML Elements using a Loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I'm currently trying to implement a function that randomly generates a random number of span tags using a loop. If I wrap the span tags in a string then the spans render onto my page as a string, however, if I don't wrap it in a string, it renders as an object.

Does anyone know of a way to handle this?

```js
function generateRandomStarCount (){
  Math.round(Math.random()*5)
  let result = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.round(Math.random()*5); i++){
    result += '<span className="fa fa-star checked"></span>'
  } 
  return result;
}
```

Comment: use document.createElement for creating span elements https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.createElement()` to create the span elements then append them to the DOM.

```js
function generateRandomStarCount () {
  let result = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.round(Math.random()*5); i++){
    let span = document.createElement('span')
    span.className = 'fa fa-star checked'
    result.push(span)
  } 

  return result;
}

let stars = generateRandomStarCount()
stars.forEach(star => document.body.appendChild(star))
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Fragments for storing all the span elements;

```
function generateRandomStarCount (){
  const fragment = new DocumentFragment();
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.round(Math.random()*5); i++){
      const span = document.createElement('span');
      span.classList.add('fa fa-star checked');
      fragment.appendChild(span)
  } 
  return fragment;
}
```

Once you get the fragments, just append wherever you want in the document.

```
 element.appendChild(fragment);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
function generateRandomStarCount() {
   element = document.getElementById('yourElement');
   for (let i = 0; i < Math.round(Math.random()*5); i++){
     var newSpan = document.createElement("span");
     newSpan.className = "fa fa-star checked";
     element.appendChild(newSpan);
   }
}
```

This code will create a random number of span inside the "yourElement" element.

Answer (score 0):

```
function generateRandomStarCount () {
  const randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 5)
  const container = document.createElement('div')

  for (var i = 0; i < randomNumber; i++) {
    const spanEl = document.createElement('span')
    spanEl.className = 'span-item'
    spanEl.innerHTML = `Count: ${i}`
    container.append(spanEl)
  }
  return container
}
```